# css an js not loaded when running sentry over nginx ingress

Tags: reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, sentry, nginx-ingress

I have sentry running in my cluster along with nginx ingress, i tried exposing it on subpath by adding these two arguments to sentry.conf.py :

SENTRY_URL_PREFIX = '/sentry'

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/sentry'

now when i hit myhost.com/sentry/ i get redirected to the login page but only the html elemtens are shown no js or css files were loaded :

[image: sentry login page]

Here is my configMap which contains both config.yaml and sentry.conf.py :

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.name }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.tools_namespace }}
data:
  config.yml: |-
    # While a lot of configuration in Sentry can be changed via the UI, for all
    # new-style config (as of 8.0) you can also declare values here in this file
    # to enforce defaults or to ensure they cannot be changed via the UI. For more
    # information see the Sentry documentation.

    ###############
    # Mail Server #
    ###############

    # mail.backend: 'smtp'  # Use dummy if you want to disable email entirely
    # mail.host: 'localhost'
    # mail.port: 25
    # mail.username: ''
    # mail.password: ''
    # mail.use-tls: false
    # The email address to send on behalf of
    # mail.from: 'root@localhost'

    # If you'd like to configure email replies, enable this.
    # mail.enable-replies: false

    # When email-replies are enabled, this value is used in the Reply-To header
    # mail.reply-hostname: ''

    # If you're using mailgun for inbound mail, set your API key and configure a
    # route to forward to /api/hooks/mailgun/inbound/
    # mail.mailgun-api-key: ''

    ###################
    # System Settings #
    ###################

    # If this file ever becomes compromised, it's important to regenerate your a new key
    # Changing this value will result in all current sessions being invalidated.
    # A new key can be generated with `$ sentry config generate-secret-key`
    # system.secret-key: 'changeme'

    # The ``redis.clusters`` setting is used, unsurprisingly, to configure Redis
    # clusters. These clusters can be then referred to by name when configuring
    # backends such as the cache, digests, or TSDB backend.
    # redis.clusters:
    #   default:
    #     hosts:
    #       0:
    #         host: 127.0.0.1
    #         port: 6379

    ################
    # File storage #
    ################

    # Uploaded media uses these `filestore` settings. The available
    # backends are either `filesystem` or `s3`.

    filestore.backend: '{{ .Values.filestore.backend }}'
    {{- if eq .Values.filestore.backend "filesystem" }}
    filestore.options:
      location: '{{ .Values.filestore.filesystem.path }}'

    {{ end }}
    {{- if eq .Values.filestore.backend "gcs" }}
    filestore.options:
      bucket_name: '{{ .Values.filestore.gcs.bucketName }}'

    {{ end }}
    {{- if eq .Values.filestore.backend "s3" }}
    filestore.options:
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.accessKey }}
      access_key: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.accessKey }}'
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.secretKey }}
      secret_key: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.secretKey }}'
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.bucketName }}
      bucket_name: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.bucketName }}'
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.endpointUrl }}
      endpoint_url: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.endpointUrl }}'
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.signature_version }}
      signature_version: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.signature_version }}'
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.region_name }}
      region_name: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.region_name }}'
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.filestore.s3.default_acl }}
      default_acl: '{{ .Values.filestore.s3.default_acl }}'
      {{- end }}
    {{ end }}

{{ .Values.config.configYml | indent 4 }}
  sentry.conf.py: |-
    # This file is just Python, with a touch of Django which means
    # you can inherit and tweak settings to your hearts content.

    # For Docker, the following environment variables are supported:
    #  SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST
    #  SENTRY_POSTGRES_PORT
    #  SENTRY_DB_NAME
    #  SENTRY_DB_USER
    #  SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD
    #  SENTRY_RABBITMQ_HOST
    #  SENTRY_RABBITMQ_USERNAME
    #  SENTRY_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
    #  SENTRY_RABBITMQ_VHOST
    #  SENTRY_REDIS_HOST
    #  SENTRY_REDIS_PASSWORD
    #  SENTRY_REDIS_PORT
    #  SENTRY_REDIS_DB
    #  SENTRY_MEMCACHED_HOST
    #  SENTRY_MEMCACHED_PORT
    #  SENTRY_FILESTORE_DIR
    #  SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL
    #  SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST
    #  SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT
    #  SENTRY_EMAIL_USER
    #  SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD
    #  SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS
    #  SENTRY_EMAIL_LIST_NAMESPACE
    #  SENTRY_ENABLE_EMAIL_REPLIES
    #  SENTRY_SMTP_HOSTNAME
    #  SENTRY_MAILGUN_API_KEY
    #  SENTRY_SINGLE_ORGANIZATION
    #  SENTRY_SECRET_KEY
    #  (slack integration)
    #  SENTRY_SLACK_CLIENT_ID
    #  SENTRY_SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET
    #  SENTRY_SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN
    #  (github plugin, sso)
    #  GITHUB_APP_ID
    #  GITHUB_API_SECRET
    #  (github integration)
    #  SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_ID
    #  SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_CLIENT_ID
    #  SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
    #  SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    #  SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_PRIVATE_KEY
    #  (azure devops integration)
    #  SENTRY_VSTS_CLIENT_ID
    #  SENTRY_VSTS_CLIENT_SECRET
    #  (bitbucket plugin)
    #  BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_KEY
    #  BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_SECRET
    from sentry.conf.server import *  # NOQA
    from sentry.utils.types import Bool, Int

    import os
    import os.path
    import six

    CONF_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)


    postgres = env('SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST') or (env('POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR') and 'postgres')
    if postgres:
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'sentry.db.postgres',
                'NAME': (
                    env('SENTRY_DB_NAME')
                    or env('POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_USER')
                    or 'postgres'
                ),
                'USER': (
                    env('SENTRY_DB_USER')
                    or env('POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_USER')
                    or 'postgres'
                ),
                'PASSWORD': (
                    env('SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD')
                    or env('POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
                    or ''
                ),
                'HOST': postgres,
                'PORT': (
                    env('SENTRY_POSTGRES_PORT')
                    or ''
                ),
            },
        }

    # You should not change this setting after your database has been created
    # unless you have altered all schemas first
    SENTRY_USE_BIG_INTS = True

    # If you're expecting any kind of real traffic on Sentry, we highly recommend
    # configuring the CACHES and Redis settings

    ###########
    # General #
    ###########

    # Instruct Sentry that this install intends to be run by a single organization
    # and thus various UI optimizations should be enabled.
    SENTRY_SINGLE_ORGANIZATION = env('SENTRY_SINGLE_ORGANIZATION', True)

    #########
    # Redis #
    #########

    # Generic Redis configuration used as defaults for various things including:
    # Buffers, Quotas, TSDB

    redis = env('SENTRY_REDIS_HOST') or (env('REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR') and 'redis')
    if not redis:
        raise Exception('Error: REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR (or SENTRY_REDIS_HOST) is undefined, did you forget to `--link` a redis container?')

    redis_password = env('SENTRY_REDIS_PASSWORD') or ''
    redis_port = env('SENTRY_REDIS_PORT') or '6379'
    redis_db = env('SENTRY_REDIS_DB') or '0'

    SENTRY_OPTIONS.update({
        'redis.clusters': {
            'default': {
                'hosts': {
                    0: {
                        'host': redis,
                        'password': redis_password,
                        'port': redis_port,
                        'db': redis_db,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })

    #########
    # Cache #
    #########

    # Sentry currently utilizes two separate mechanisms. While CACHES is not a
    # requirement, it will optimize several high throughput patterns.

    memcached = env('SENTRY_MEMCACHED_HOST') or (env('MEMCACHED_PORT_11211_TCP_ADDR') and 'memcached')
    if memcached:
        memcached_port = (
            env('SENTRY_MEMCACHED_PORT')
            or '11211'
        )
        CACHES = {
            'default': {
                'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
                'LOCATION': [memcached + ':' + memcached_port],
                'TIMEOUT': 3600,
            }
        }

    # A primary cache is required for things such as processing events
    SENTRY_CACHE = 'sentry.cache.redis.RedisCache'

    #########
    # Queue #
    #########

    # See https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/server/queue/ for more
    # information on configuring your queue broker and workers. Sentry relies
    # on a Python framework called Celery to manage queues.

    rabbitmq = env('SENTRY_RABBITMQ_HOST') or (env('RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR') and 'rabbitmq')

    if rabbitmq:
        BROKER_URL = (
            'amqp://' + (
                env('SENTRY_RABBITMQ_USERNAME')
                or env('RABBITMQ_ENV_RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER')
                or 'guest'
            ) + ':' + (
                env('SENTRY_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD')
                or env('RABBITMQ_ENV_RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS')
                or 'guest'
            ) + '@' + rabbitmq + '/' + (
                env('SENTRY_RABBITMQ_VHOST')
                or env('RABBITMQ_ENV_RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST')
                or '/'
            )
        )
    else:
        BROKER_URL = 'redis://:' + redis_password + '@' + redis + ':' + redis_port + '/' + redis_db


    ###############
    # Rate Limits #
    ###############

    # Rate limits apply to notification handlers and are enforced per-project
    # automatically.

    SENTRY_RATELIMITER = 'sentry.ratelimits.redis.RedisRateLimiter'

    ##################
    # Update Buffers #
    ##################

    # Buffers (combined with queueing) act as an intermediate layer between the
    # database and the storage API. They will greatly improve efficiency on large
    # numbers of the same events being sent to the API in a short amount of time.
    # (read: if you send any kind of real data to Sentry, you should enable buffers)

    SENTRY_BUFFER = 'sentry.buffer.redis.RedisBuffer'

    ##########
    # Quotas #
    ##########

    # Quotas allow you to rate limit individual projects or the Sentry install as
    # a whole.

    SENTRY_QUOTAS = 'sentry.quotas.redis.RedisQuota'

    ########
    # TSDB #
    ########

    # The TSDB is used for building charts as well as making things like per-rate
    # alerts possible.

    SENTRY_TSDB = 'sentry.tsdb.redis.RedisTSDB'

    ###########
    # Digests #
    ###########

    # The digest backend powers notification summaries.

    SENTRY_DIGESTS = 'sentry.digests.backends.redis.RedisBackend'

    ##############
    # Web Server #
    ##############

    # If you're using a reverse SSL proxy, you should enable the X-Forwarded-Proto
    # header and set `SENTRY_USE_SSL=1`

    if env('SENTRY_USE_SSL', False):
        SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
        SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
        CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
        SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
    SENTRY_URL_PREFIX = '/sentry'
    FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/sentry'
    SENTRY_WEB_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
    SENTRY_WEB_PORT = 9000
    SENTRY_WEB_OPTIONS = {
        'http': '%s:%s' % (SENTRY_WEB_HOST, SENTRY_WEB_PORT),
        'protocol': 'uwsgi',
        # This is need to prevent https://git.io/fj7Lw
        'uwsgi-socket': None,
        'http-keepalive': True,
        'memory-report': False,
        # 'workers': 3,  # the number of web workers
    }

    ###############
    # Mail Server #
    ###############

    email = env('SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST') or (env('SMTP_PORT_25_TCP_ADDR') and 'smtp')
    if email:
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.backend'] = 'smtp'
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.host'] = email
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.from'] = env('SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL')
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.username'] = env('SENTRY_EMAIL_USER') or ''
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.password'] = env('SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD') or ''
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.port'] = int(env('SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT') or 25)
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.use-tls'] = env('SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS', False)
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.list-namespace'] = env('SENTRY_EMAIL_LIST_NAMESPACE') or 'localhost'
    else:
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.backend'] = 'dummy'

    # The email address to send on behalf of
    SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.from'] = env('SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL') or 'root@localhost'
    # If you're using mailgun for inbound mail, set your API key and configure a
    # route to forward to /api/hooks/mailgun/inbound/
    SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.mailgun-api-key'] = env('SENTRY_MAILGUN_API_KEY') or ''
    # If you specify a MAILGUN_API_KEY, you definitely want EMAIL_REPLIES
    if SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.mailgun-api-key']:
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.enable-replies'] = True
    else:
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.enable-replies'] = env('SENTRY_ENABLE_EMAIL_REPLIES', False)
    if SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.enable-replies']:
        SENTRY_OPTIONS['mail.reply-hostname'] = env('SENTRY_SMTP_HOSTNAME') or ''



    ##########
    # Docker #
    ##########

    # Docker's environment configuration needs to happen
    # prior to anything that might rely on these values to
    # enable more "smart" configuration.

    ENV_CONFIG_MAPPING = {
        'SENTRY_SECRET_KEY': 'system.secret-key',

        'SENTRY_SLACK_CLIENT_ID': 'slack.client-id',
        'SENTRY_SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET': 'slack.client-secret',
        'SENTRY_SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN': 'slack.verification-token',

        'SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_ID': ('github-app.id', Int),
        'SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_CLIENT_ID': 'github-app.client-id',
        'SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_CLIENT_SECRET': 'github-app.client-secret',
        'SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_WEBHOOK_SECRET': 'github-app.webhook-secret',
        'SENTRY_GITHUB_APP_PRIVATE_KEY': 'github-app.private-key',

        'SENTRY_VSTS_CLIENT_ID': 'vsts.client-id',
        'SENTRY_VSTS_CLIENT_SECRET': 'vsts.client-secret',
        'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID': 'auth-google.client-id',
        'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET': 'auth-google.client-secret',
    }


    def bind_env_config(config=SENTRY_OPTIONS, mapping=ENV_CONFIG_MAPPING):
        """
        Automatically bind SENTRY_OPTIONS from a set of environment variables.
        """
        for env_var, item in six.iteritems(mapping):
            # HACK: we need to check both in `os.environ` and `env._cache`.
            # This is very much an implementation detail leaking out
            # due to assumptions about how `env` would be used previously.
            # `env` will pop values out of `os.environ` when they are seen,
            # so checking against `os.environ` only means it's likely
            # they won't exist if `env()` has been called on the variable
            # before at any point. So we're choosing to check both, but this
            # behavior is different since we're trying to only conditionally
            # apply variables, instead of setting them always.
            if env_var not in os.environ and env_var not in env._cache:
                continue
            if isinstance(item, tuple):
                opt_key, type_ = item
            else:
                opt_key, type_ = item, None
            config[opt_key] = env(env_var, type=type_)

    # If this value ever becomes compromised, it's important to regenerate your
    # SENTRY_SECRET_KEY. Changing this value will result in all current sessions
    # being invalidated.
    secret_key = env('SENTRY_SECRET_KEY')
    if not secret_key:
        raise Exception('Error: SENTRY_SECRET_KEY is undefined, run `generate-secret-key` and set to -e SENTRY_SECRET_KEY')

    if 'SENTRY_RUNNING_UWSGI' not in os.environ and len(secret_key) < 32:
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        print('!!                    CAUTION                       !!')
        print('!! Your SENTRY_SECRET_KEY is potentially insecure.  !!')
        print('!!    We recommend at least 32 characters long.     !!')
        print('!!     Regenerate with `generate-secret-key`.       !!')
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')

    # Grab the easy configuration first - these are all fixed
    # key=value with no logic behind them
    bind_env_config()

    # If you specify a MAILGUN_API_KEY, you definitely want EMAIL_REPLIES
    if SENTRY_OPTIONS.get('mail.mailgun-api-key'):
        SENTRY_OPTIONS.setdefault('mail.enable-replies', True)

    if 'GITHUB_APP_ID' in os.environ:
        GITHUB_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['repo']
        GITHUB_APP_ID = env('GITHUB_APP_ID')
        GITHUB_API_SECRET = env('GITHUB_API_SECRET')

    if 'BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_KEY' in os.environ:
        BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_KEY = env('BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_KEY')
        BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_SECRET = env('BITBUCKET_CONSUMER_SECRET')

{{- if .Values.metrics.enabled }}
    SENTRY_METRICS_BACKEND = 'sentry.metrics.statsd.StatsdMetricsBackend'
    SENTRY_METRICS_OPTIONS = {
        'host': '{{ .Values.name }}-metrics',
        'port': 9125,
    }
{{- end }}

{{ .Values.config.sentryConfPy | indent 4 }}
```

And here is my ingress resource :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sentry-ingress
  namespace: tools
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  labels:
    app: sentry-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /sentry/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: sentry
              servicePort: 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the browser's Dev Tools to see what urls are trying to be loaded for CSS? It may be the case that you need to add an ending `/` at the end of the configured URL_PREFIX.